# Object is binded to input field after click

Tags: angular

I have input:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="rowOrder.item" [attr.disabled]="!rowOrder.editRow ? '' : null" >
```

And a void which is related to save value from this input to object editedRowOrder when i click

```
  editRowOrder(rowOrder:RowOrderModel){
    this.editedRowOrder = rowOrder;
    rowOrder.editRow = !rowOrder.editRow;
  }
```

but when i after changing the input, the data in editedRowOrder is continuing changing and follows input.

The question is: How can i change the data in input which looks like above and after clicking editedRoworder saves data and doesnt follow input until next click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used lodash Clonedeep to make a copy to avoid binding to object and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).